# Cordova sqlite-storage no funciona con iOS 10

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, plugin

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para **iOS** y **Android** con **Apache Cordova**. Estoy usando el *plugin* `sqlite-storage` para almacenar datos localmente.

El código que utilizo es el que se muestra en este sitio:

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

La App la he probado tanto en Android como en el simulador de iOS.

En Android funciona bien, al igual que en *iOS 9.3*.

El problema que tengo, es cuando lo pruebo en *iOS 10*.

El código de JavaScript es el mismo para ambas plataformas y para las diferentes versiones del sistema operativo móvil de *Apple*.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Alguien sabe si debo de utilizar un código diferente para *iOS 10*?

Dejo abajo un código simple que, funciona bien con *iOS 9.3*, pero **NO funciona en iOS 10**.

```
var db = null;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'demo.db', location: 'default'});
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (name, score)');
  }, function(error) {
    alert('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
  }, function() {
    alert('Tabla creada!');
  });
```

Lo que obtengo en *iOS 9.3* es un *alert* que dice: "Tabla creada!", pero al probarlo en *iOS 10* no obtengo ningún resultado.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer no eres el unico que le falla este plugin con `iOS 10`, hay muchos `issues` sobre los errores que puede ocacionar, algunos dan como solucion ejecutar `cordova prepare` antes de ejecutar la aplicación en el simulador o en el dispositivo. Otra de las soluciones que dan es que trabajes con la version `iOS` `cordova-ios-4.3.0` y esto no te causara ningun problema!

[GitHub issue Cordova SQLite Storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/567)

[Cordova prepare para XCODE 8 y superior](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12046)